# Expo Push Notifications does not work in production

Tags: android, push-notification, expo

I use the Expo Push Notifications system to send notifications to users of my app. (made in react native)

Everything worked fine locally via expo but since going into production, nothing works on android. I followed the configuration specified at this address to the letter (and several times): https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/using-fcm/

But nothing helps, I do not receive anything on android, even on expo now that I have done the configuration.

Is there something special to do in addition?

I specify that my configurations in the google-services.json file correspond to the project created on Google Cloud Platform, and that I have specified the relative path of this file in app.json.

Thanks in advance.